# Google sign up method

Tags: firebase

Currently I'm making the login and sign up activities for my app and I'm thinking in just have the google sign up method from firebase , because if  you have a google play account you have a gmail account to register.
And my question is: Do you think I should add the login method via email / password or keep the google login method because it is easier and faster to sign in?

thanks

Comment: Is your app an Android app? Web?

Comment: It's an android app.@HondaGuy